# How to find semantic similarity using gensim and word2vec in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, word2vec, gensim

I have a list of words in my python programme. Now I need to iterate through this list and find out the semantically similar words and put them into another list. I have been trying to do this using gensim with word2vec but could find a proper solution.This is what I have implemeted up to now. I need a help on how to iterate through the list of words in the variable sentences and find the semantically similar words and save it in another list.

```
import gensim, logging

import textPreprocessing, frequentWords , summarizer
from gensim.models import Word2Vec, word2vec

import numpy as np
from scipy import spatial

sentences = summarizer.sorteddict

logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s : %(levelname)s : %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)
model = word2vec.Word2Vec(sentences, iter=10, min_count=5, size=300, workers=4)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't care about *proper* clusters, you can use this code:

```py
similar = [[item[0] for item in model.most_similar(word)[:5]] for word in words]
```

---

If you really want to clusterize the words, here are few notes:

- There can be several such clusters.
- The number of clusters depends on a *hyperparameter*, some threshold. When the threshold is big, all of the words are similar and belong to the same cluster, when it's too small, none of them are.
- Words can be naturally included *transitively* into a cluster, i.e. `A` is similar to `B` and `B` is similar to `C`, so all three should be in the same cluster. This means you'll have to implement some sort of graph traversal algorithm.
- The performance greatly depends on the training corpus: only if it's large enough, gensim word2vec will be able to capture proper similarity. Gemnsim hyperparameters and text pre-processing thus also matter.

Here's a naive and probably not very efficient algorithm and identifies clusters:

```py
model = gensim.models.word2vec.Word2Vec(sentences, iter=10, min_count=5, size=300, workers=4)
vocab = model.wv.vocab.keys()

threshold = 0.9
clusters = {}
for word in vocab:
  for similar_word, distance in model.most_similar(word)[:5]:
    if distance > threshold:
      cluster1 = clusters.get(word, set())
      cluster2 = clusters.get(similar_word, set())
      joined = set.union(cluster1, cluster2, {word, similar_word})
      clusters[word] = joined
      clusters[similar_word] = joined
```

Comment: Thanks alot.This makes sense.